# How to create script to automatically move mouse relative to current mouse position at a 45deg angle

Tags: c#, macros, autohotkey

So the purpose of the program is that upon pressing xbutton2 I want the program to automatically move my mouse at a 45 degree angle relative to my mouse's current position and automatically press the K key afterwards.

I was considering just having the .ahk script run a get mouse position then move relative move to an X and Y coordinate however it didn't work as any move movement already in place would override it.

I also got a C# script from another coder who was able to achieve a similar output, however it's not functional in-game and wasn't built for the same purpose (can be repurposed) I will include the paste-bin if it helps.

https://pastebin.com/dxXKfQpj > C# Code

Here is my code:

````
*xbutton2::
        MouseGetPos, x, y
        MouseMove, x+5.5, y+6.5
        MouseMove, x+5.5, y+6.5
        Send K
return```
````

Comment: What is the problem with your code? In what way it doesn't work?

Comment: Quite a few problems in the AHK code, but before I start addressing them, can you explain exactly what sort of behavior you're after? Currently the code seems like you'd move the mouse pointer 5.5 pixels on the x-axis and 6.5 pixels on the y-axis. To not even consider it's impossibility due to half pixels not existing, it seems weird. Just move once when XButton2 is pressed? Not keep moving while it's held? Or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

What I havve used years ago for an application to control other applications the hard way:

```
   public class Win32Input
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendInput", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);

        private enum InputType
        {
            INPUT_MOUSE = 0,
            INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1,
            INPUT_HARDWARE = 2,
        }

        [Flags()]
        private enum MOUSEEVENTF
        {
            MOVE = 0x0001,  // mouse move 
            LEFTDOWN = 0x0002,  // left button down
            LEFTUP = 0x0004,  // left button up
            RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008,  // right button down
            RIGHTUP = 0x0010,  // right button up
            MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020,  // middle button down
            MIDDLEUP = 0x0040,  // middle button up
            XDOWN = 0x0080,  // x button down 
            XUP = 0x0100,  // x button down
            WHEEL = 0x0800,  // wheel button rolled
            VIRTUALDESK = 0x4000,  // map to entire virtual desktop
            ABSOLUTE = 0x8000,  // absolute move
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct MOUSEINPUT
        {
            public int dx;
            public int dy;
            public int mouseData;
            public MOUSEEVENTF dwFlags;
            public int time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct INPUT
        {
            public InputType type;
            public MOUSEINPUT mi;
        }

        public static uint Move(int x, int y)
        {
            float ScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
            float ScreenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

            INPUT input_move = new INPUT();
            input_move.type = InputType.INPUT_MOUSE;

            input_move.mi.dx = (int)Math.Round(x * (65535 / ScreenWidth), 0);
            input_move.mi.dy = (int)Math.Round(y * (65535 / ScreenHeight), 0);
            input_move.mi.mouseData = 0;
            input_move.mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF.MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF.ABSOLUTE);
            input_move.mi.time = 0;
            input_move.mi.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();

            INPUT[] input = { input_move };
            return SendInput(1, input, Marshal.SizeOf(input_move));
        }
    }
```

I remember copying this code from a internet resource. Possibly SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move it 45 degrees it should be that displacement in x is equal to y so :

```
xbutton2::
        MouseGetPos, x, y
        MouseMove, x+6.5, y+6.5
        MouseMove, x+6.5, y+6.5
        Send K
return
```

I guess your displacements were ok for you, maybe your problem is that you are playing a game which skews AHK capability to move and send keys correctly. [Here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/111737-how-to-make-ahk-work-in-most-games-the-basics/) is another forum talking about in more details.

You also say movements are overriden. Are you running more than one AHK script at a time? If so maybe one of them gets stuck in a loop (happened to me).

Hope that helps!